# Android SeekBar value not properly being passed to calculate method

Tags: java, android

in the OnProgressChanged method of the OnSeekBarChangeListener class, I have a method that calculates the tip percentage and displays it on the screen. It only seems to work from values 0 and 100, not any value in between.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progress = ((int)Math.round(progress/5 ))*5;
                seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                String tipValStr = String.valueOf(progress);
                tipVal = progress;
                tvTipVal.setText(tipValStr);
                //Toast.makeText(TipCalc.this, "Seekbar Value : " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                calculate(progress);
            }

public void calculate(int tip){
        try{
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        billVal = Double.parseDouble(etBillVal.getText().toString());
        //tipVal = sbTipVal.getProgress();
        tipValue = billVal * (tip/100);
        billTotal = billVal + tipValue;
        tvBillVal.setText("$"+df.format(billVal));
        tvTipValue.setText("+ $" + df.format(tipValue));
        tvBillTotal.setText("$"+df.format(billTotal));
        Toast.makeText(TipCalc.this, "$"+df.format(billTotal), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //billVal = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're problem is an integer division. int `tip` divided by `100`, will always return 0, unless `tip` value is 100, in which case the result is `1`.

Try defining `tip` as a `float` instead.-

```
public void calculate(float tip);
```

and

```
tipValue = billVal * (tip / 100.0f);
```

Comment: Glad it helped :) Please, consider upvoting/accepting the answer so that other users can spot it as the right one.